# How to create 2 archetypes out of the same project having different modiles in maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project with module A and module B i want to create 2 artifacts separately 1. with module A + module B packaged and another one with only Module B packaged. Both of these would have different names. How can I do it in a single shot.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this myself. We can use something called activeByDefault as false for whatever module we need to ignore.

Comment: This is related to profiles which sounds like the wrong way... can you create a full example on github or a like?